# Differences between switch statements in C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, switch-statement

I'm just starting out teaching myself C#, and in a tutorial on Switch statements, I read:

> The behavior where the flow of execution is forbidden from flowing
>   from one case block to the next is one area in which C# differs from
>   C++. In C++ the processing of case statements is allowed to run from
>   one to another.

Why does it stop after one case statement in C#? If you can use the `break` statement to stop at any point, is there any reason in C# vs. C++ to having it stop after a match is found? And if you wanted more than one case in C#, would you have to use another Switch statement?

Comment: I guess it balances out the fact that you can use strings.

Comment: Prohibiting fall-through makes C# less "messy"

Comment: @Greg, Though I must say I've used the fall-through maybe once before. If it doesn't fall through, why bother needing the break in the first place?

Comment: It annoys the heck out of people coming from C... Btw why did't they remove the break keyword altogether, while they were at it ?

Comment: I could have sworn that i've successfully used the fall-through method in c# before...  Maybe i'm remembering this wrong

Comment: @SamIam: C# does allow for fall through as long as the case body is empty.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: No idea, I've always wondered this myself.  `break` should be implicit. A `fallthrough` keyword could have been added.

Comment: @EdS.: `goto case` is as good as a `fallthrough` keyword, but even more powerful.

Comment: @EdS. Or the `continue` keyword for this purpose.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Now that would annoy the heck out of C and C++ programmers... my `continue` statement no longer applies to the containing loop, wth?!?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Sure, that works.  I just don't get why the default behavior isn't implicit.

Comment: @Ed: Because people who are transcribing (or copy+paste) C and C++ code would be very unhappy if fallthrough disappeared silently.  As well, a `case` does not have to end in `break`, any control statement is valid.  I actually wrote a bug report against the documentation for that one.

Comment: @BenVoigt: But your `break` would ! I find this "feature" retarded however. If you're into variants of C, at least go for identical control flow and operators.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: I'm not sure what you're saying.  In C and C++, `break` applies to the `switch`.  Ditto for C#.  In C and C++, `continue` applies to the loop.  Ditto for C#.  They DID choose to use similar semantics, and I think that's the right choice.

Comment: Related: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/718068/cs0163-documentation-and-error-text-do-not-cover-all-common-causes

Comment: @BenVoigt: `Because people who are transcribing (or copy+paste) C and C++ code would be very unhappy if fallthrough disappeared silently.` That seems like a terrible reason to implement a (non) feature for a completely different language :).  I can appreciate practical problems, but that seems like a stretch.

Comment: I don't see how asking about tradeoffs between two particular solutions is not constructive or unfit for Q&A.

Comment: @EdS.If MS wanted to create a completely different language, they shouldn't have called it C# in the first place... ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C# has `goto case`*value*, which has all the benefits of fallthrough but is harder to do by accident.

[Example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx)

Comment: Would you look at that. That's pretty nifty.

Comment: wait, wasn't `switch` added to C++ to get rid of C's `goto` spaghetti?

Comment: @Gregory: No, C has `switch` too (since waaaaay back, it's meant to be the source code version of a jump table)

Comment: Maybe the story was that it was added to C to fix basic; but I seem to recall that there was some kind of a controversy behind the inclusion of `switch` in to the langue in order to "fix" all the problems that `goto` code created. I'll have to try and see if I can find the reference I'm thinking of...

Comment: @Gregory: `switch` is definitely not an evolution of C `goto` or `if`.  It could be considered a C equivalent to [BASIC "computed goto"](https://www.atarimagazines.com/compute/issue87/The_Power_Of_ON-GOTO_And_ON-GOSUB.php), something that C's `goto` does not support at all and is closer to C function pointers.

Comment: I guess, ["The switch statement has been extended,"](https://www.thinkage.ca/gcos/expl/b/manu/manu.html#Section1) would imply that `switch` was in the original Bell Lab's B, and therefore likewise in K&R C... I defiantly do not need to drag up the whole "to goto, or not to goto" debate especially when the [goto wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto) is a good read on the topic; however it still makes me snicker to think that in C# `goto` is coming to `switch`'s rescue.

Comment: also, and maybe more importantly on-topic, is it true that it "has all the benefits of fallthrough"? In the since that, and to the extent that you have a good compiler, the resulting compiled code does not have a whole lot of unnecessary short jumps? one for each `goto case` instead of actually reordering the conditions and falling-through.

Comment: @Gregory I don't know that the compiler smartly reorders the blocks for you, but if you write a jump to the immediately following case, I'm confident the optimizer will remove the useless short jump.

Answer (score 16):

Technically, this is not correct: C# does allow fall-through when the body of the `case` is empty:

```
switch(val) {
case 1:
case 2:
    Console.WriteLine("small");
    break;
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
case 6:
case 7:
    Console.WriteLine("medium");
    break;

 default:
    Console.WriteLine("large");
    break;
}
```

Allowing implicit fall-through after a non-empty body in C/C++ is done by mistake more often than not. That is why the designers of C# decided against allowing it.

Comment: What I never understood is... if fall-through is intended to not be allowed, why on heart do we have to add `break` explicitly?

Comment: @Servy: ಠ_ಠ Seriously? And why a `switch` when correctly used would be a bad thing?

Comment: @LightStriker Well, it was mostly a joke, but it did have a grain of truth.  The idea was that, while sometimes appropriate, is often mis-used.  Making it harder to use means that it's more likely to be used only when it's truly appropriate.

Comment: @LightStriker There is a long-standing holy war between "switch users" and "not switch users". Don't involve yourself in it, lest its fury consume your soul forevermore.

Comment: @ean5533: ಠ_ರೃ As you wish good sir, I shall remain above such puny dispute and not question why a feature was made difficult to use on purpose.

Comment: @LightStriker There is a long-standing joke among the hard-core OO programmers that every `switch` statement in your program is a reminder of a missed opportunity to use inheritance. Heck, I've seen fanatics who say the same thing about `if` statements :-)

Comment: Surely the above code is legal in C#, but whether you name it "fall-through" or not, depends on terminology. According to the terminology used in the C# Spec, the above `switch` statement consists of three _switch sections_. The first section has two _switch labels_, the second section has five labels, and the third and last section has one label. The entire region inside the braces `{ ... }` is called the _switch block_. With this terminology, fall-through from a _section_ to the next _section_ is never allowed. Source: [C# Spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Now, I would ask them how they intend to test the value of an enum without any `if` or `switch` and making it easy for the user to select this value in an interface. A list of empty classes? Good god! How about a bitfield? o.O

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You are absolutely correct, C# standard introduced a very good terminology to explain the switch statement without getting into much trouble with empty vs. non-empty blocks. C and C++, however, lack the same terminology (because there was no need to introduce it in the first place). I used "fall-through" in the C/C++ sense, not in the C# sense.

Comment: @LightStriker: One can build a `switch` from an array of delegates... `if`, `switch`, `do`, `while`, `for` are not actually needed for conditional code.  Actually `try`+`catch`+divide by zero makes for an adequate `if` replacement, if you're trying to obfuscate code.

Answer (score 4):

I think the argument is that fall through switch statements in C++ generally caused more problems than they solved. I.e. when they fell through when it wasn't the programmers intent, they just forgot the `break`. So C# did away with it.

Same with a lot of other "features" in C++. It's not that they weren't occasionally useful, it's just that more often they were harmful. Like evaluating just about anything as a bool, so in C# you can't do:

```
if(1) 
{

}
```

Because evaluating ints as bools caused a lot of hard to find bugs.

Comment: This "feature" also annoys the heck out of C programmers. They could at least have non-null references evaluate to true.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: I think the main problem is mixing up `=` and `==`. If a non-null reference evaluated to true, then `if (myFoo=myBar)` when would evaluate as true in C++, but it'll cause a compiler error in C#. Which is not a bad thing IMHO.

Comment: @AlexandreC. That could cause all sorts of mayhem if you had a nullable boolean.

Comment: @Servy: Do nullable booleans even get lifted correctly in `if` statements ?

Comment: @AlexandreC. No, and that's my point.  (Currently you need to convert it to a non-nullable boolean.)  You're suggestion would either result in that happening, which would cause confusion and be ambiguous, or be inconstant with the behavior of reference types, also causing confusion and complaints.  I'm not saying you couldn't make it work somehow, I'm just saying that whatever you do, it will be...messy and large groups of people will be confused.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: You'd need something like `if (myNullableBool.HasValue && myNullableBool.Value)`, which, admittedly, is kinda awkward.

Comment: @Servy: I assume that's why Alexandre said "non-null *references*".  `Nullable<System.Boolean>` is not a reference.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, and that's why I said you would either needs to make it try to do something, which would have problems, or result in it being "inconsistent" because all sorts of people would expect `Nullable` instances to evaluate to true/false just as references do, and it would be a points of confusion if they weren't.  Then of course there's the issue of boxed nullable types.  As I said, you could find a way of making it all work, but regardless of what you do it will be messy and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

C#'s version is less error prone - nothing will explode in your face if you forget to write a `break`, which happens. It also looks a little nicer. Then again, there's precious little reason to use switch statements most of the time anyways (often it just ends up being a poor implementation of type dispatch, which is built-in in both languages through class inheritance).

Comment: I agree that there aren't too many cases where a `switch` is really useful. It's a neater version of a long list of `if/else` statements and is flawed in the same way as a long list of `if/else` statements.

Answer (score 0):

this probably falls squarely into the anti-pattern realm, but if you really want fall-through behavior this should probably be close to the same as a jump table

```
using System;

namespace MyApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int day = 4;
      switch (day) {
        case 1: goto d1;
        case 2: goto d2;
        case 3: goto d3;
        case 4: goto d4;
        case 5: goto d5;
        case 6: goto d6;
        case 7: goto d7;
      }    
      d1: Console.WriteLine("Monday");
      d2: Console.WriteLine("Tuesday");
      d3: Console.WriteLine("Wednesday");
      d4: Console.WriteLine("Thursday");
      d5: Console.WriteLine("Friday");
      d6: Console.WriteLine("Saturday");
      d7: Console.WriteLine("Sunday");
    }
  }
}
```